# Set remote_user for set of tasks in Ansible playbook without repeating it per task

Tags: ansible

I am creating a playbook which first creates a new username. I then want to run "moretasks.yml" as that new user that I just created. Currently, I'm setting remote_user for every task. Is there a way I can set it for the entire set of tasks once? I couldn't seem to find examples of this, nor did any of my attempts to move remote_user around help.

Below is main.yml:

```
---
- name: Configure Instance(s)
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: true

  tags:
    - config
    - configure

  tasks:
    - include: createuser.yml new_user=username
    - include: moretasks.yml new_user=username
    - include: roottasks.yml #some tasks unrelated to username.
```

moretasks.yml:

```
---
  - name: Task1
    copy: 
      src: /vagrant/FILE
      dest: ~/FILE
    remote_user: "{{newuser}}"

  - name: Task2
    copy: 
      src: /vagrant/FILE
      dest: ~/FILE
    remote_user: "{{newuser}}"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all you surely want to use `sudo_user` (remote user is the one that logs in, `sudo_user` is the one who executes the task).

In your case you want to execute the task as another user (the one previously created) just set:

```
- include: moretasks.yml
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: "{{ newuser }}"
```

and those tasks will be executed as {{ newuser }} (Don't forget the quotes)

Remark: In most cases you should consider `remote_user` as a host parameter. It is the user that is allowed to login on the machine and that has sufficient rights to do things. For operational stuff you should use `sudo` / `sudo_user`

Comment: I thought sudo_user was the one that executed only if you needed to do some sudo action? I want to note, the users I'm creating don't have sudo privileges. All the actions in "moretasks" are local to their home. Is it still appropriate (misleading?) to use the sudo_user approach? (The approach did work)

Comment: You are right, @Shark. From the docs, sudo_user: This is the default user to sudo to if --sudo-user is not specified or ‘sudo_user’ is not specified in an Ansible playbook. The default is the most logical: ‘root’.

Comment: Note that `sudo` and `sudo_user` have been deprecated in favor of `become` and `become_user`. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#become

Answer (score 11):

You could split this up into to separate plays? (playbooks can contain multiple plays)

```
---
- name: PLAY 1
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
    - include: createuser.yml new_user=username
    - include: roottasks.yml #some tasks unrelated to username.

- name: PLAY 2
  hosts: all
  remote_user: username
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - include: moretasks.yml new_user=username
```

There is a gotcha using separate plays: **you can't use variables set with `register:` or `set_fact:` in the first play to do things in the second play** (this statement is not entirely true, the variables are available in `hostvars`, but I recommend not using variables between roles). Defined variables like in group_vars and host_vars work just fine.

Another tip I'd like to give is to look into using `roles` http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html. While it might seem more complicated at first, it's much easier to re-use them (as you seem to be doing with the "createuser.yml"). Looking at the type of things you are trying to achieve, the 'include all the things' path won't last much longer.

Comment: @ProfHase85's answer is correct, I didn't quite catch the fact that in your case you don't need to log in as the "newuser". Still leaving the answer up, splitting playbooks and using roles are valid tips.

Comment: Yeah, just starting the structure of this code base. As it gets more elaborate, I will probably look into seeing how effective roles can be. To me, it just looked like a way to reference different yml files without actually "including" them. It didn't seem to add any features that you couldn't accomplish otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Kind of inline with your issue. Hope it helps. While updating my playbooks for Ansible 2.5 support for Cisco IOS network_cli connection

Credential file created with ansible-vault: auth/secrets.yml

```
---
creds:
  username: 'ansible'
  password: 'user_password'
```

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: ios
  gather_facts: yes
  connection: network_cli
  become: yes
  become_method: enable
  ignore_errors: yes

  tasks:
  - name: obtain login credentials
    include_vars: auth/secrets.yml

  - name: Set Username/ Password
    set_fact:
     remote_user: "{{ creds['username'] }}"
     ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ creds['password'] }}"

  - name: Find info for "{{ inventory_hostname }}" via ios_facts
    ios_facts:
      gather_subset: all
    register: hardware_fact
```

Running playbook without auth/secrets.yml creds:

```
ansible-playbook -u ansible -k playbook.yml -l inventory_hostname
```